# Javascript/jquery - onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with a strange problem where a javascript function isn't getting invoked when I click on `submit button(LOG IN)` from inside a form.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
    $('#loginBtn').click(function () {
        $(this).html('<img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/images/fbloader.gif" />');
    });
    </script> 
    </head>
</html>
```

Is there anything different I should do here? I'm unable to figure this out. Please could I ask for help?

Comment: What is your strang problem? What is expected behaviour?

Comment: Hello Tung - Thankyou for jumping in.  The first part of the problem where there was a typo is solved. The second part of the problem is  `$(this).html('<img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/images/fbloader.gif" />');` isn't replacing the button with the image that I want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the extra `)` at the end of `function hideBtn()`.

It should look like this

```
function hideBtn(){
  alert('hello');
};
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"   href="app/js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"   href="app/js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"   href="app/css/bootsnipLogin.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/js/login.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="app/image/favicon.ico" />

    </head>

    <body >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card card-container">
        <br/>
        <center><img src="app/image/wd-logo.gif"></center>
        <br/><br/>
        <img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card" src="app/image/avatar_2x.png" />
        <br/>
        <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p> 
        <form class="form-signin" action="" method="post">
            <input  id="username" name="username"  placeholder="User Name"  class="form-control" required autofocus>
            <br/><br/><br/>
            <input  type="password"  id="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required >
            <br/><br/><br/>
            <div align="center">
            <span id = "errorspan"><?php echo $error; ?></span>
            </div>
            <br/><br/><br/>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" name="submit" id="loginBtn">SIGN IN</button>
        </form><!-- /form -->
        </div><!-- /card-container -->
    </div><!-- /container -->   
          <script>
    $('#loginBtn').click(function(){
    //  alert('as');
        $(this).html('<img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/images/fbloader.gif" />');
    });
    </script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Munawir - Thankyou for spotting the typo. Now that it works, I updated the code to replace the button with a `GIF`. However that doesn't seem to take effect. Would you have an idea about that please?

Comment: `$(this).html();` is a jquey not javascript

Comment: You need to pass a reference to `this` in the JavaScript function call. eg:

`<button onClick="hideBtn(this)"></button>`

`function hideBtn(thisEle){ thisEle.innerHTML = 'img tag here' ; }`

Comment: I've updated the question to remove the `onClick` function. Instead using Jquery now. With Jquery, `    $('#loginBtn').click(function () {
        $(this).html('<img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/images/fbloader.gif" />');
    });` - This doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong here? I did try `replaceWith` too. I'd like to understand what's the right way to do please.

Comment: You need to link jquery like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: That's a good spot. Still doesn't replace the button. This still doesn't replace the button :-( Neither does it alert a `hello` if I added one. Will see what else is missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107293/discussion-between-munawir-and-usert4jju7).

Comment: As you advised, placing the function at the end of body helped.

Answer (score 2):

There's an extra ');' in your script. Remove it and it will work.

```
function hideBtn(){
    //$(this).html('<img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/images/fbloader.gif" />');
    alert('hello');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the extra ) then your code will work properly like below

```
 function hideBtn()
    {
       alert('Hii');
    }
```